# How do I use a version folder for my @types/definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json, definitelytyped

I want to get the typings for react-router, but when you have this in your package.json dependencied:

```
{
  "@types/react-router": "^4.0.3"
}
```

It uses the standard index.d.ts from the DefinitelyTyped library (the one that is correct for react-router 1.0).

I know there are folders in DefinitelyTyped for [v2 and v3](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-router) - I believe v3 will have everything I want.

How can I use the v3 folder in my project?

Do I have to manually put in the typings from the folder, or is there already an automated method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @ after module name. For example, in order to install @types/react-router v3, run:

```
npm install @types/react-router@v3
```